# Is there a way to specify per-feature project.scripts in pyproject.toml using hatch?

Tags: python, entry-point, hatch

I have a small python project "`tsdb`" using *hatch* for packaging.
The projects develops a python package and includes a demo using Streamlit. Since not everyone needs the demo and since Streamlit has a lot of dependencies, I make it an *optional dependency* (or a *feature*, as it is called in the documentation):

```ini
[project.optional-dependencies]
gui = [ "streamlit" ]
```

To make the demo easier to use, I add the following *entry point* (*script*):

```ini
[project.scripts]
tsdb-demo = "tsdb.scripts.run_streamlit:run"
```

This works, except that `tsdb-demo` throws an error when the package is installed without `[gui]` (since it is missing Streamlit).
It there a way to specify that the entry point should get installed only with `[gui]`?

And if not, what is the recommended/standard approach in these cases: should I put the demo into a separate package. And if so, can/should this be done within the same git repo, or should I have two separate repos?